# Tomcat 8 limit memory

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I installed Tomcat 8 with Java 8 on VPS server with 1024 RAM. But when I deploy war package I get error for memory.

I tried to limit the allocated memory with this setenv.sh script:

```
#! /bin/sh
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms48m -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

But I get this error when I start Tomcat:

```
[root@ip-172-31-28-148 bin]# ./shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
[root@ip-172-31-28-148 bin]#
```

Do you have any idea what is the proper way to limit Java to use 512 MB RAM memory?

Comment: That's PermSize, not memory.  They redid the memory model for JDK8.  No more perm gen: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Comment: What configuration I need to add to setenv.sh in order to restrict to 700 MB JVM allocated RAM?

Comment: So if you want to limit overall memory usage you'd want -Xmx500 or something (it's not all heap after all...)

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, the system property `PermSize` and `MaxPermSize` have been removed in Java8 and their use raise a warning.

You could use `MaxMetaspaceSize` instead but your question is not clear. With PermSize, your reduce the memory allocated to the Permanent Generation, objects which are needed by the JVM and your container at all time.

If you want to reduce the memory used by your JVM (only the heap --> arrays and instances), you should use Xms (size at **s**tart) and Xmx (ma**x** size).

For example :
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M